# How to relocate an element in a matrix to a random empty location in another row?

Tags: python, numpy, random, reinforcement-learning

Let's say I have a 5*5 matrix.

```py
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0]]
```

For example:

I want to get '4' but '5' is in front of it. I need to relocate '5' which is unnecessary here and place it in any random available location other than the row it was in earlier.

so the matrix should look like this after the relocation

```py
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 5. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

and if I need '3' it should relocate '4' and '5' to random locations.

please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: is this a list? This is actually a 1D list, the newlines used to format the code don't affect the actual list object. Also where does the `5` move in your example? It rather looks like you removed it

Comment: Python doesn't have a built-in type for matrices. You can treat a list of a list as a matrix but your example manages just a list

Comment: I'm dealing with 2D array and to create the matrix I use sizeRow*sizeColumn

Comment: @PrashantRavulakolu: What you're showing us is an ordinary list (or perhaps a 1D array) with 25 entries that just happens to be formatted over multiple lines. Moreover, it's definitely not "all zeros" as you say.

Comment: I have corrected it..please have a look

Comment: While you talk of a `matrix` and use a `numpy` tag, your example looks too much like a list or list of lists.  Hence you get  list based comments and answer.  But maybe that's the best you'll get; it doesn't look like an especially numpy friendly task.  Also you should have shown your own effort to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer, I assume that the matrix is implemented as a list of lists such as

```
a = [[1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

The function below

- accepts two arguments, `a`, a 2-dimensional matrix implemented as a list of lists, and `n`, the number in `a[0]` (i.e. the first row of `a`) you want to shift right to the end of `a[0]`.
- `idx` is assigned the index in `a[0]` where `n` occurs.
- The elements in the list `to_relocate` are all the elements in `a[0]` to the right of `n`.
- `a[0] = [0.] * (len(a[0]) - (idx + 1)) + a[0][:idx + 1]` shifts elements of `a[0]` right, filling the left with zeros.
- We then randomly place the items in `to_relocate` to an element in any row of `a` other than row 0.
- While doing so, in the set `do_not_remove`, we record the indices of `a` corresponding to elements that are replaced by elements in `to_relocate` so that we do not attempt to place more than one element in `to_relocate` at the same location in `a`.

```
from random import randrange
def change_random(n, a):
     # get index of n in a[0].
     idx = a[0].index(n)
     # values to relocate.
     to_relocate = a[0][idx + 1:]
     # shift a[0] right (filling left with zeros)
     a[0] = [0.] * (len(a[0]) - (idx + 1)) + a[0][:idx + 1]

     # records indices corresponding to elements of a 
     # that have already been replaced by elements in to_relocate.
     do_not_remove = set()
     for num in to_relocate:
          while True:
               # draw indices at random from set of valid indices (not row 0)
               ij = (randrange(1, len(a)), randrange(0, len(a[0])))
               # if element corresponding to ij has not been previously replaced, break
               if ij not in do_not_remove:
                    break
          do_not_remove.add(ij)
          a[ij[0]][ij[1]] = num

change_random(3, a)
print(a)
```

**Sample Session**:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
 [4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Comment: @Prashant Ravulakolu Please let me know if this is what you were looking for or not!

Comment: @Shinwazu No worries! Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks again....I changed it a little and it works like a dream. all thanks to you